# Returning Managed C# List to Unmanaged C++ code

Tags: c#, list, unmanaged, managed

I have a C# dll ( for which register for COM interop option is set).

This C# dll has the below interface and class

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    bool IsNameExists(string name);
    List<string> GetNameList();
} 

public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{

    public bool IsNameExists(string name)
    {
        //DO Something

    }
    public List<string> GetNameList()
    {

        // DO something
    }

}
```

I need to call the methods IsNameExists and GetNameList from unmanaged C++.

```
#import "..\..\ProdCon\bin\ProdCon.tlb" raw_interfaces_only

   void main()
   {    
        HRESULT hr =::CoInitialize(NULL);
        IMyInterface pIMyInterface(__uuidof(MyClass));

        VARIANT_BOOL bRet = FALSE;

        BSTR bstrName = ::SysAllocString(_T("RAJESH"));
        hr =  pIMyInterface->IsNameExists(bstrName,&bRet);

    }
```

So I created COM object as above and called the IsNameExists mehtod without any issue.

Since GetNameList method returns list, I am getting the below warning

> 'MyDll.IMyInterface.GetNameList(#0), MyDll'. Warning: Type library
>   exporter encountered a generic type instance in a signature. Generic
>   code may not be exported to COM.

Please help me how to return C# list to unmanaged C++ code. So that unmanaged C++ code can use this list.

Comment: COM knows beans about .NET generics.  Return an ArrayList or the non-generic IEnumerator or your own collection interface instead.

Answer (score 1):

'Generic code may not be exported to COM.' => hence its the type parameter string in public List GetNameList().  Thus essentially you need access to a non-generic c# method to get the data.

If you have control of the MyClass codebase you could (for example) add a:

```
public string[] GetNameArray()
{
   return GetNameList.ToArray();
}
```

If not then you'll need to write a proxy/wrapper class to do something similar to the above and expose that via COM, either as a one off or a 'general' methodology using reflection say.

See for example http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/Jul/10/Generics-and-COM-Interop-dont-mix

Comment: can you please help me how the string[] will be accessed from unmanaged C++

Comment: not sure of the question, _IF_ you can change MyClass and IMyInterface then I'm suggesting an option is adding the above method, whence you call it as you call IsNameExists

Comment: I can add the above method GetNameArray() in C#. I want to know how the string[] can be retrived from C++.